# Data noise in bluetooth headset when coupled to an analog(ue) audio mixer via signal transformer

Tags: transformer, analog, noise, bluetooth, microphone

Long time (lurker) fan of StackExchange, first time poster.

I am attempting to connect an **Astro A50 bluetooth headset** via its own basestation's analog(ue) combined line input/output (4-pole CTIA socket), using an **OEP A262A1E** audio transformer (inside an **A262CAN** screening can and also inside a metallised instrument box) to isolate and balance the mic signal for improved CMRR as it is fed into the audio mixer. The headphone signal comes from that same mixer. I am hearing a crazy amount of 'data' noise on the mic signal (that's fed back into the headphones), and I have tried a bunch of different grounding strategies to try to reject/reduce it - see the attached sketch for the wiring diagram:

[image: Bluetooth headset connection circuit]

Here are the grounding strategies I've tried:

1. A+B+C+D ('ground all the things')
2. A+B separated from C+D
3. A separated from B, and C+D
4. A separate from B seperate from C separate from D (none tied to any other)

All four of these strategies sound the same in the earphones - wideband noise across the whole audio spectrum (checked with an 20Hz-20kHz spectrum analyser), which is periodically modulated by regular clicks; it just sounds like data noise rather than hum/hiss etc. The Astro A50 basestation is powered by USB and (annoyingly) has to be powered by a PC as it won't wake up unless it talks to an operating system, so it can't be run off a 5V phone charger or (battery) power bank. So, we have both the PC's ground and the mixing desk's ground in play when the headphones are fed from the mixing desk...

There is a single instance where there is *NO* such noise on the mic signal, which is when I plugged my (mobile/cell) phone into the headphone socket, running off its own internal battery. The mic signal into the audio desk was clean, and the music played off my phone into the headphones was also clean, and there was only a *single* electrical ground being used, which was from the PC powering the headset base station. So I guess it could be a ground-loop issue? Any ideas?

[I used to be super hot on this sort of thing, twenty years ago... In fact this transformer was carefully desoldered from a different, unfinished circuit that I made in 1994!]

(Here's the transformer's datasheet:)
[image: A262A1E Datasheet]

Comment: Yes, a ground loop issue is the most likely.

Comment: @Andyaka - what would you proposed solution be, to remove the ground loop?

Comment: I cannot visualize your full system so I can't make a suggestion.

Comment: @andyaka What other information would you need to visualise my full system? I'm happy to provide it, if it allows you or others to offer a potential solution, thanks!

Comment: Somewhat off topic from your original question but have you tried making a small loopback connection on the USB D+/D- lines to see if that's all that the base station is looking for from an OS?  If that's all it is it may allow you actively use an external USB charger if you just make a small loopback on the data lines.

Comment: @snowmanemperor - this is an excellent suggestion, I have not tried this yet, but I will be delighted if it works (because it might allow me to power the basestation from a battery source, removing one of the electrical grounds)!

Comment: if it's really a PC-mixer ground loop, you need to isolate D from A/B/C most likely. But I'm not convinced. Try feeding tone at around 300Hz into the mic (you will need a resistive pad, something like 20k/200R (-40dB with 200R output impedance, but experiment) and look at the audio out of that jack. You may see digital noise. Also try shorting the mic out and measure output 20Hz-20kHz on the jack. Could be that the output is just noisy and you're stuck with it. Anyway the noise is almost certainly conducted not radiated (find out by varying distance), if so screening won't help.

Comment: In configuration 4, what were ABCD tied to, if anything?

Comment: @Aaron in config 4 they were all isolated from each other, but I *suspect* that D, being signal ground, may have been tied to (or somehow coupled with) mains ground on the bluetooth basestation (via the powering PC's USB socket and its PSU) and/or to mains/chassis ground on the audio mixer via the 1/4" jack, cos if they weren't then my gut feel is that the noise wouldn't be as prevalent, right?

Comment: @AndrewC, yeah, make sure D isn't connecting to chassis.

Comment: @Aaron, Yep, but I think that D will _always_ be connected to the mixer chassis by virtue of (or should that be 'by vice of'?!) the mixer's headphone socket, which has a metal body and is mounted directly in the metal chassis itself.

Comment: @danmcb Thanks, I will see if I can try this out.

Comment: @Aaron, I can't remove the signal ground from between the 1/4" jack socket (headphone feed from mixer) and the 1/8" jack socket (headset) because the left and right headphone would then have no return path, and would be open-circuit... If only the headset used a FIVE-pole jack that provided a clean, isolated ground line for the mic alone, as well as a dedicated ground for headphones!

Comment: @AndrewC, What I meant was to make sure that there is no continuity between A and D.

Comment: @Aaron ah, OK, I see what you mean. Yes, there's no link between A and D now 

Comment: @danmcb "Could be that the output is just noisy and you're stuck with it. Anyway the noise is almost certainly conducted not radiated"... how right you were! Kudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** *I have finally found that the awful noise is being passed from the PC that powers the base station, via USB, and the base station has abysmal filtering (if any) on the incoming DC power.* As soon as I power the base station from a laptop that's running off its internal battery, the wideband, modulated noise goes away. Plug in the laptop's PSU and the noise returns. What a truly *awful* analogue signal path decoupling from digital and power lines! ‍♂️ **/UPDATE**

Comment: I'm glad that I stumbled upon your post and thread now. Sadly, found it only after buying the Astro's :(
Were you able to find any solutions or concepts on how to fix this issue? Small update: In my case white noise is present even with the laptop running on battery

Comment: @Niki, I toyed with the idea of trying to trick the basestation into thinking it was connected to a laptop by shorting a couple of the USB contacts together, allowing me to power the basestation from a smoothed/denoised DC supply, but I haven't got around to trying that yet! 